# How to iterate through a sub section of a 2d list?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, iteration

I'm making an update board for connect4 and trying to stack a one on top of the previous one on the board. But iterating through the board is confusing me. I'm aware that the for loop is not correct because it's just a single number. But how would I accomplish this(playcol is constant for this it would be 3). Couldn't find much on google besides possibly using slicing?

'''

```
   board = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,1,0,0,0]]
   def updateboard(playcol,board):
       x=0
       for x in board[x][playcol]:
           if board[x][playcol] == 0:
               try:
                   continue
               #if it goes too far past it will throw index error and return the previous
               except IndexError:
                   board[x-1][playcol] = 1
           #else there is a number already there and make the one before it a number
           elif board[x][playcol] != 0:
               board[x-1][playcol] = 1
       print(board)
```

'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do, there are most likely more efficient ways to do this using numpy.  However, since this is a simple function and you are just using lists of list, I thought would implement a solution for that.

Instead of using the try and excepts, I would just loop through the length of the board.   I am not sure what kind of error handling you want on your board but i simply made it print out that you can't make that play.

See below.

```
board = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,1,0,0,0]]
def updateboard(playcol,board):
    for i in range(len(board)):
        if board[i][playcol]==1:
            if (i-1) >=0:
                board[i-1][playcol]=1
            else:
                print("cannot play that column")
        elif i==len(board) and board[i][playcol]==0:
            board[i][playcol]=1
    print(board)
updateboard(3,board)

[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks that was indeed what I was looking for. Didn't think you could do len(board) if it was 2d but guess it makes sense. Also I was trying to use try and except for no particular reason so sorry if that was confusing.